# Why json data not displaying after running app in on iOS emulator for react-native?

Tags: react-native, rest

I have one json api, I try to fetch data with react-native. My application running but nothings display on screen. I try to handle characters in data arrays, I don't know why it is not working, any idea will be appreciated.

**App.js:**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react- 
native';

const myURL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode";

const App = () => {
const[isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [name, setName] = useState([]);
const [air_date, setAirDate] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
fetch(myURL)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {
setData(json.characters);
setName(json.name);
setAirDate(json.air_date);
})
.catch((error) => alert(error))
.finally(() => setLoading(false));

}, []);

return (
 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  {isLoading ? (
  <ActivityIndicator />
   ):(
    <View>
    <Text>{name}</Text>
    <FlatList
    data={data}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
    <Text>
      {item}
    </Text>
   )} 
   />
  <Text>{air_date}</Text>
  </View>
  )}
  </SafeAreaView>
 );
 };

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 });

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this;

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
const[isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const myURL = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode";


useEffect(() => {
fetch(myURL)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => {
setData(json.results);
})
.catch((error) => alert(error))
.finally(() => setLoading(false));

}, []);

return (
 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  {isLoading ? (
  <ActivityIndicator />
   ):(
    <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (           
               <Text>
                 {item.name}
               </Text>         
            )}
          />
  )}
  </SafeAreaView>
 );
 };

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 },
 });

 export default App;
```